# JS. Как сделать автозаполнение input игнорируя ввод пользователя?

Tags: javascript, input, action

В общем суть такая: имеем поле для ввода, и не обращая внимания на то, что вводит пользователь, с каждым нажатием клавиши (любой), в поле будет вписываться за ранее заготовленный текст. Можете рабочий пример накатать? Буду благодарен.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так..

```js
let text = "hello", i = 0;

function g(e){
  if (i<text.length) i++;    
  e.target.value = text.slice(0, i);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="g(event)">
```